# openMP parallelize for-loop slower compared to serial

Tags: c++, for-loop, openmp

I´m having problems to parallelize a for-loop. I have already read a lot of threads in this forum, but none of them helped. The code is quite simple, so I don´t really see where I should change something.

```
    #pragma omp parallel for
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < num_bodies; ++i){
          Planet* planet = Planet::planets[i];
          planet->updateVelo(planet->getAccel(), dt);
          planet->updatePos(planet->getVelo(), dt);
          planet->resetAccel();
        }
```

"num_bodies" is 200 at the beginning and decreases to 133 over a couple of iterations, so no really big numers. I am updating the objects in the vector Planet::planets by updating the member variables. 
"dt" is a value that is never changed.
Without openMP, the whole loop needs around 0.00002 seconds whereas it takes between 0.001 and 0.01 seconds with openMP activated. I have tried several ways do get the parallelized version faster, but nothing helped.

Thank you!

Comment: Parallelization is not free! There are rather expensive things going on in the background needed to even start up the parallel loop, and `num_bodies` is quite tiny. Try again with a million bodies or so, then you should easily see a positive effect.

Comment: I disagree, the code is so simple that having more items will only increase the overhead in respect to actual work done.

Comment: ***Without openMP, the whole loop needs around 0.00002 seconds whereas it takes between 0.001 and 0.01 seconds with openMP activated. I have tried several ways do get the parallelized version faster, but nothing helped.*** Then this section of code is not well suited for parallelization. Although like others said if num_bodies was much higher the time to create the threads relative to the time to process would decrease meaning at some point it could be useful to use parallel for.

Comment: thanks so far! The problem is, this is an exercise for university and we have got a given .txt file we shall use to test, which has 200 bodies. I have asked others how they parallelized it and they said it could be done the way I showed above. But maybe they were not right aswell.

Comment: Have you implemented all the work needed for each iteration? It would make a big difference if there was more to do for each iteration.

Comment: Yes the serial code is complete and works fine.

Comment: Then I think this is all you can do. Although this appears to be a very bad exercise for demonstrating openmp parallel for. I would have expected an example that clearly shows an advantage when splitting the work on a modern 4+ threaded processor. That is unless the purpose of the exercise was for you to learn the things we talk about in this thread.

Answer (score 3):

200 is a very small number, it is likely that the extra time needed to set up the multi threading framework is longer that the time you save by parallelizing the job, try to increase the number of loops and also make sure you have used the proper compiler switch(es) es. $gcc -fopenmp

Comment: 200 could be a large enough number if the processing for each item was longer.